# Encrypting XML with a public key in C#: how to create the SessionKey

Tags: c#, xml, public-key-encryption

Regarding this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746(v=vs.110).aspx

I would like to encrypt the XML using a business partner's Public Key, which we have in a text file. So instead of this:

```
sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
sessionKey.KeySize = 256;
```

and then this:

```
EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);
```

I need to create a **sessionKey** *using the partner's X509Certificate* and send that key as the second parameter to the **EncryptData** method.  What are the steps to produce a sessionKey from the partner's certificate?

Comment: pass the users X509Certificate into the encryption method. It would be easier to see if you posted your whole code...

Comment: I don't have any code yet. The datatype of the second parameter of the EncryptData method is not a "X509Certificate", so your suggestion is unclear to me.

Comment: Then try to make your code ??? Just use the X509Certificate as the encryption Key of the IV. With a Key of 256 bytes you need a 32 character long string. The IV has to be 128 bytes with a 16 character long string. If the X509Certificate is always less than 16 characters use it as the IV and add the extra characters until it adds up to 16. If it is higher than that do the same but use it as the Key value.